# How to check whether vim has enabled line autobreak at 80 characters or not?

Tags: vim

Hi my vim automatically insert a newline character after 80 character, which is not my intended behavior. However, I cannot find any line width config in my vimrc file.

How to check whether some config is enabled for this? I want to disable this auto-line-break feature.

Thanks to @romainl reminder, here is the output of the command ":verbose set fo tw":

```
  formatoptions=tcq                                                                                                                                                      
        Last set from ~/.vim/view/~=+Downloads=+c.txt= line 68                                                                                                           
  textwidth=79                                                                                                                                                           
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/python.vim line 20
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't just display the text on the next line without actually adding a newline character? You can display the line numbers with `:set number`

Comment: Automatic wrapping happens when: `:help 'formatoptions'` contains `t`, and `:help 'textwidth'` is a number over zero. While you are editing a buffer where you get that undesired behaviour, do `:verbose set fo tw` and add the output of that command to your question.

Comment: @Einliterflasche yeah I am sure. I tested by repeatedly adding a word "abc " (a whitespace at the end), and then the 1st line ends at 79th character, and I see number 2 for the next line.

Comment: @romainl your cmd seems captured the root cause. The output of cmd ":verbose set fo tw" is added to the question description.

Answer (score 1):

So…

- To reiterate what I wrote in the comments section, automatic line breaks happen when you have `t` in `:help 'formatoptions'` *and* `:help 'textwidth'` is set to a non-zero value. Individually, those conditions don't lead to automatic line breaks, it is only when they are both true that you get automatic line breaks.
- The `t` in `formatoptions` is not a problem in and of itself. It is part of of the default value anyway so you can pretty much forget about it.
- You get those automatic line breaks because `textwidth` is set to `79` in `~/.vim/plugin/python.vim`. Change its value to `0` to disable the feature.

But the interaction of those two files is worrying so I think you should take a look at [this document](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc/).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to configure the following options in your `.vimrc`

- [`wrap`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wrap%27)
- [`textwidth`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27)   Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be
  broken after white space to get this width.  A zero value disables
  this.
- [`wrapmargin`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wrapmargin%27) Number of characters from the right window border where wrapping
  starts.  When typing text beyond this limit, an EOL will be inserted
  and inserting continues on the next line.

Comment: thanks. I posted my output of "verbose fo tw" command, and I feel it will lead to a solution (even though I don't know it now).